# Maven resolve dependencies issues

Tags: maven, cassandra, vert.x

I want to know what is the best aproach in a Maven conflict situation like this one

I have this library

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Which has a dependency with

```
netty-transport 4.15.final
```

And I have this other dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Which contains the dependency

```
netty-transport 4.0.37
```

It´s seems like the cassandra version with the 4.15.final does not work

So normally in this cases what you have to do, if I exclude the netty
from the vertx dependency it´s most probably it wont work with the version of Cassandra, and the other way around.

Are those library with those versions condemned to do not work together?

Regards.

Comment: How did you conclude on cassandra doesn't work on netty 4.15 final ? Most of the time higher version is backward compatible with previous one. And, as both libs use the netty transport with same major version i.e. 4 , it could work.

Comment: Since having the maven dependency 4.15.final in the classpath return a NullPointer and with lower version works just fine. I understand your point, I don't understand quite well what´s happening here.

Comment: Check if you can use OSGi framework that allows to use multiple jars of same artifact however with different versions.

Comment: @ShaileshPratapwar I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with details on the NPE. I have tried Vert.x 3.3.3 with the 3.3.1 Datastax driver and it works for me.

Comment: Yes with 3.3.1 works for me as well

Comment: I mean with Vertx version 3.3.1 and Cassandra 3.1.0 works

Comment: Did you figure out the solution to the original problem of versions?